# How to avoid delay on minimize

Tags: windows-7, conemu

When I minimize/restore the ConEmu window using the corresponding hotkey, restoring takes an instant while minimizing has a little delay (almost 1 second). How can I prevent this delay when minimizing the window?

```
System details:  
Win7 x64  
default ConEmu settings (just quake mode enabled),  
default cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug, and may be not...

Strange to hear "minimize" for Quake mode. Did you mean "slide up"?

If this is a bug - it is better to create a new issue on project bugtracker. And most likely I'll need logs from ConEmu started with `/log4` argument (logs, reproducing delay). And ConEmu configuration of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I mean "slide up" - but there is no animation. I think that could be the problem, and it feels like animated slide-up should be instead of this delay. Is it possible to diagnose why there is no slide?

Comment: latest update solved the problem, sliding works well.

Comment: Thought, you are not using **ConEmu** internal hotkey for Minimize/Restore.